# Sum column only 2 digits after precision (no round)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I have a float type column with numbers that have 6 digits after precision. I want to sum the column only by 2 digits after precision.

For example, I have 1.257868 and 1.258778 as values and I want to get the result of 2.50 as result of sum.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want something like:

```
sum(floor(mycol * 100) / 100)
```

The expression within the `sum()` performs the truncation to 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 3 argument form of [`round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select sum(round(mycol, 2, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

[odbc truncate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/odbc-scalar-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#numeric-function)

```
select v.val, {fn TRUNCATE(v.val, 2)} as trncted, sum({fn TRUNCATE(v.val, 2)}) over() as sumtrncated
from 
(values (1.257868), (1.258778)) as v(val);
```